# Keep coordinate not changing for Mouse Click Event on plotWidget (pyqtgraph) after image zoom in/out

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouseevent, pyqtgraph

I am using PyQt5 to design GUI for image analysis.The image window is designed using plotWidget, and hence user can zoom in/out the displayed image using mouse.
**Issue description**: when user click a position, the software has mouse click event with callback of the (x, y) coordinate of the mouse on the image. However after image zooming in/out,  the coordinates callback at same clicked point is not changing. (I expected the coordinates should change with IMAGE zoom in/out, NOT the absolute positions respect to the GUI window).

Is there way to achieve this?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Qt reports the mouse position in pixels relative to the widget receiving the mouse event. You need to *map* the mouse position to the coordinate system of the image. Pyqtgraph's image analysis example shows one way to do this--if you get the event directly from the ImageItem, it will already have been mapped for you:

https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/imageAnalysis.py#L97

An alternative is to do the mapping yourself:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

class PW(pg.PlotWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.PlotWidget.__init__(self)
        self.img = pg.ImageItem(np.random.normal(size=(100, 100)))
        self.addItem(self.img)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        scene_pos = self.mapToScene(ev.pos())
        img_pos = self.img.mapFromScene(scene_pos)
        print(img_pos)
        return pg.PlotWidget.mouseMoveEvent(self, ev)

pg.mkQApp()
pw = PW()
pw.show()
```